# Command to remove diacritics

Tags: unicode, lua

I would like a command that removes diacritics. I can write such a function in Python:

```
import unicodedata

def dediacritic(word):
    result = u"".join([unicodedata.normalize("NFD", x)[0] for x in word])
    return result

print("Ἰακώβ", dediacritic("Ἰακώβ"))
```

This seems to work well:

```
$ dediacritic.py
Ἰακώβ Ιακωβ
```

But I want to be able to do it in Latex. Is it possible to write such a function (perhaps using Lua, since I use lualatex)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIXTwoText-Regular}

\newcommand\dediacritic[1]{#1}  % put what here?

\begin{document}
Ἰακώβ \dediacritic{Ἰακώβ}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can do the equivalent of your given code (normalizing every codepoint individually to NFD and using the first glyph) using my `unicode-algos` moodule, but this will not reliably remove diacritics. For once it only works with NFC input text and even then it fails for e.g. Korean text or characters which don't have a precomposed form.

Comment: You could try normalizing to NFD and then using character properties to identify diacritics, but it all depends on what you are actually trying to archive with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The direct equivalent to the code you provided would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__mk_dediacritic_naive_codepoint:n #1 {
  \tl_head:f { \codepoint_to_nfd:n { `#1 } }
}
\cs_new:Npn \mk_dediacritic_naive:n #1 {
  \str_map_function:nN { #1 } \__mk_dediacritic_naive_codepoint:n
}

\cs_new_eq:NN \dediacritic \mk_dediacritic_naive:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Ἰακώβ \dediacritic{Ἰακώβ}
\end{document}
```

This only works in LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX since it assumes that tokens are full Unicode codepoints.

This will break in many more complicated cases though, so usually you would want something along the lines like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_map_function:nN { e }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_head:n { f }
\cs_new:Npn \__mk_dediacritic_decomposed_codepoint:n #1 {
  \str_if_eq:eeF { \str_head:f { \codepoint_to_category:n { `#1 } } } { M } {
    #1
  }
}
\cs_new:Npn \__mk_dediacritic_codepoint:n #1 {
  \str_map_function:eN { \codepoint_to_nfd:n { `#1 } } \__mk_dediacritic_decomposed_codepoint:n
}
\cs_new:Npn \mk_dediacritic:n #1 {
  \str_map_function:eN { #1 } \__mk_dediacritic_codepoint:n
}

\cs_new_eq:NN \dediacritic \mk_dediacritic:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Ἰακώβ \dediacritic{Ἰακώβ}
\end{document}
```

This checks for every decomposed codepoint if the category starts with `M`, indicating a (combining) mark character (aka. a diacritic) and removes these.